# CSS animation error with attr() variable from javascript

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to have a css animation and have 3 files.
Here's the html file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class = "tag" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- header => class => id => inline style-->
    <div class="main-content">
        <h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nisl eros, 
pulvinar facilisis justo mollis, auctor consequat urna. Morbi a bibendum metus. 
Donec scelerisque sollicitudin enim eu venenatis. Duis tincidunt laoreet ex, 
in pretium orci vestibulum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis pharetra luctus lacus ut 
vestibulum. Maecenas ipsum lacus, lacinia quis posuere ut, pulvinar vitae dolor.
Integer eu nibh at nisi ullamcorper sagittis id vel leo. Integer feugiat 
faucibus libero, at maximus nisl suscipit posuere. Morbi nec enim nunc. 
Phasellus bibendum turpis ut ipsum egestas, sed sollicitudin elit convallis. 
Cras pharetra mi tristique sapien vestibulum lobortis. Nam eget bibendum metus, 
non dictum mauris. Nulla at tellus sagittis, viverra est a, bibendum metus
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="bounceLeft"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then here is the javascript file...

```
setInterval(()=>{
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-content")[0].setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-content")[0].setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);}
, 1000);
```

And here is the css file.

```
@keyframes colChange{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    33% {background-color: rgb(0, 38, 255);}
    66% {background-color:  rgb(20, 192, 72);}
    100% {background-color: red}
}

@keyframes bounceLeft{
    0%{left: calc(attr(data-width)/2-230); top:0px;}
    50%{left: calc(attr(data-width)/2-200); top:attr(data-height);}
    100%{left: calc(attr(data-width)/2-200); top:0px;}
}

.main-content{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(255,0,0,0));
    outline-width: 7px;
    outline-color: yellow;
    outline-style: outset;
    
}

.main-content{
    height:auto;
}

#bounceLeft{
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid white;
    animation-name: bounceLeft;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div :hover{
    outline-style: dashed;
} 

body{
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: colChange;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(214, 161, 16);
}
h2{
    text-align: center;
}
```

The problem with this is that the div isn't moving at all. When I inspected it, I realized that the attr() part in the css wasn't working, but I don't know how to fix it. I want to make an animation to have the div bounce up and down on the screen, beside the placeholder text. Here is the assumed error [pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDx6I.png)

EDIT: I want the white box to bounce up and down

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){  
   document.getElementsByClassName("main-content")[0].style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
   document.getElementsByClassName("main-content")[0].style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}, 1000);
 var m = 200;
```

```css
@keyframes colChange{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    33% {background-color: rgb(0, 38, 255);}
    66% {background-color:  rgb(20, 192, 72);}
    100% {background-color: red}
}

@keyframes bounceLeft{
    0%{left: calc(attr(data-width)/2-230); top:0px;}
    50%{left: calc(attr(data-width)/2-200); top:attr(data-height);}
    100%{left: calc(attr(data-width)/2-200); top:0px;}
}

.main-content{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(255,0,0,0));
    outline-width: 7px;
    outline-color: yellow;
    outline-style: outset;
    
}

.main-content{
    height:auto;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#bounceLeft{
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid white;
    animation-name: bounceLeft;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div :hover{
    outline-style: dashed;
} 

body{
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: colChange;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(214, 161, 16);
}
h2{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
        <h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nisl eros, 
pulvinar facilisis justo mollis, auctor consequat urna. Morbi a bibendum metus. 
Donec scelerisque sollicitudin enim eu venenatis. Duis tincidunt laoreet ex, 
in pretium orci vestibulum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis pharetra luctus lacus ut 
vestibulum. Maecenas ipsum lacus, lacinia quis posuere ut, pulvinar vitae dolor.
Integer eu nibh at nisi ullamcorper sagittis id vel leo. Integer feugiat 
faucibus libero, at maximus nisl suscipit posuere. Morbi nec enim nunc. 
Phasellus bibendum turpis ut ipsum egestas, sed sollicitudin elit convallis. 
Cras pharetra mi tristique sapien vestibulum lobortis. Nam eget bibendum metus, 
non dictum mauris. Nulla at tellus sagittis, viverra est a, bibendum metus
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="bounceLeft"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the CSS calc formats are incorrect. Any minus operator must have spaces before and after it. Also to do a division you must put that in a calc.

So, here are the keyframes spelled out with correct spacing and included calc

```
@keyframes bounceLeft{
    0%{left: calc(calc(attr(data-width) / 2) - 230); top:0px;}
    50%{left: calc(calc(attr(data-width) / 2) - 200); top:attr(data-height);}
    100%{left: calc(calc(attr(data-width) / 2) - 200); top:0px;}
}
```

And the snippet which shows the animation.

```js
setInterval(()=>{
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-content")[0].setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-content")[0].setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);}
, 1000);
```

```css
@keyframes colChange{
    0% {background-color: red;}
    33% {background-color: rgb(0, 38, 255);}
    66% {background-color:  rgb(20, 192, 72);}
    100% {background-color: red}
}

@keyframes bounceLeft{
    0%{left: calc(calc(attr(data-width) / 2) - 230); top:0px;}
    50%{left: calc(calc(attr(data-width) / 2) - 200); top:attr(data-height);}
    100%{left: calc(calc(attr(data-width) / 2) - 200); top:0px;}
}

.main-content{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(255,0,0,0));
    outline-width: 7px;
    outline-color: yellow;
    outline-style: outset;
    
}

.main-content{
    height:auto;
}

#bounceLeft{
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid white;
    animation-name: bounceLeft;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div :hover{
    outline-style: dashed;
} 

body{
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: colChange;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(214, 161, 16);
}
h2{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <!--   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>-->
    <!-- header => class => id => inline style-->
    <div class="main-content">
        <h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nisl eros, 
pulvinar facilisis justo mollis, auctor consequat urna. Morbi a bibendum metus. 
Donec scelerisque sollicitudin enim eu venenatis. Duis tincidunt laoreet ex, 
in pretium orci vestibulum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis pharetra luctus lacus ut 
vestibulum. Maecenas ipsum lacus, lacinia quis posuere ut, pulvinar vitae dolor.
Integer eu nibh at nisi ullamcorper sagittis id vel leo. Integer feugiat 
faucibus libero, at maximus nisl suscipit posuere. Morbi nec enim nunc. 
Phasellus bibendum turpis ut ipsum egestas, sed sollicitudin elit convallis. 
Cras pharetra mi tristique sapien vestibulum lobortis. Nam eget bibendum metus, 
non dictum mauris. Nulla at tellus sagittis, viverra est a, bibendum metus
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="bounceLeft"></div>
```